# sql select count group by with zero counts

Tags: java, sql, jpa

In jsf I have a named query that count and groups data.

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Zdarzenie.SelectCount", query = "select new Answer((type(z)) ,month(z.data), year(z.data), count(z)) from Eventz where type(z) in :givenEvents and z.data >= :dataOd and z.data<= :datDo group by Month(z.data), year(z.data), type(z) order by month(z.data), year(z.data) asc "),
```

it works fine - it counts events for each month in given period. BUT - when the count is '0' then it just skips this in result list. So, the reulst look like:

```
[ADD, 1, 2013, 33]
[ADD, 2, 2013, 25]
[REMOVE 2, 2013, 1]
```

and I need it to look like this:

```
[ADD, 1, 2013, 33]
[REMOVE, 1, 2013, 0]
[ADD, 2, 2013, 25]
[REMOVE 2, 2013, 1]
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I guess for this you need to put check in code

Comment: I'm not that good with sql - could you propose a query with check?

Comment: That's because having count 0 means you don't have any rows on table containing those values. You can't have rows on result that don't exist on table.

To say it different way. How should database know that you want to have result [REMOVE, 1, 2013, 0]? How should it know that you don't want to see result [FOOBAR, -7, 1353, 0]? That combination also has zero count on table.

Comment: But database has been asked to look for REMOVE event with date 1,2013, so when it's not in databse, I just want it to give me zero as an answer, not  skiping result

Comment: Database has been asked to give results that match those given parameters. It can't give results it doesn't have.

Comment: But as freak suggested earlier you should probably solve this problem with Java code instead of SQL (or database in general)

Comment: So you will have to iterate through results and add missing rows with Java.

Comment: any hints? I just cannot think of elegant way of doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the rest I think with that query you simply cannot get nonexistent data from DB. Also any complicated queries are IMHO not a solution, because no one will understand them + you could get in performance problems (you/your team will invest more time to debug those SQL queries than you planned).

The only solution would be to fill in the needed data in Java, after you fetch it from DB.

Answer (score 3):

To simplify your example if you have a table T that contains:

```
Type   | Month | Year
-------+-------+-------
ADD    |   1   | 2013
ADD    |   1   | 2013
REMOVE |   1   | 2013
REMOVE |   1   | 2013
ADD    |   2   | 2013
ADD    |   2   | 2013
REMOVE |   3   | 2013
```

As you have noticed, if you do:

```
SELECT  Type, Month, Year, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM    T
GROUP BY Type, Month, Year;
```

You will get:

```
Type   | Month | Year | Count
-------+-------+------+-------
ADD    |   1   | 2013 |   2
REMOVE |   1   | 2013 |   2
ADD    |   2   | 2013 |   2
REMOVE |   3   | 2013 |   1
```

So you are missing the counts for ADD for month 3, and REMOVE for month 2. This is because the database can't include results that don't exist.

How to solve this depends on exactly how you want your results to show, if you want all possible combinations, you would need to use something like:

```
SELECT  Types.Type, Years.Year, Months.Month
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT Type FROM T) AS Types
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Year FROM T) AS Years
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Month FROM T) AS Months
```

This will give a cartesion product of all 3 columns:

```
Type   | Month | Year
-------+-------+-------
ADD    |   1   | 2013
ADD    |   2   | 2013
ADD    |   3   | 2013
REMOVE |   1   | 2013
REMOVE |   2   | 2013
REMOVE |   3   | 2013
```

You can then LEFT JOIN your original table to get the counts:

```
SELECT  Types.Type, Years.Year, Months.Month, COUNT(T.Type) AS Count
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT Type FROM T) AS Types
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Year FROM T) AS Years
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Month FROM T) AS Months
        LEFT JOIN T
            ON T.Type = Types.Type
            AND T.Year = Years.Year
            AND T.Month = Months.Month;
```

Which will give the desired result of:

```
Type   | Month | Year | Count
-------+-------+------+--------
ADD    |   1   | 2013 |   2
ADD    |   2   | 2013 |   2
ADD    |   3   | 2013 |   0
REMOVE |   1   | 2013 |   2
REMOVE |   2   | 2013 |   0
REMOVE |   3   | 2013 |   1
```

I have tried to make the above as DBMS inspecific as possible since none was supplied in the question, but it may require minor tweaks for your DBMS.

Comment: this solution is good for sql - but I'm ot writing query in plain sql, so it's not helping me. Thanks for help:)

Comment: +1 from me as this is an interesting solution (although it needs in practice IMHO too much effort)

Comment: This solution has some limitations. For example if you don't have ADD or REMOVE for 3/2013 you would like to see zero count for both ADD and REMOVE. This query can't produce that result because there are not any rows having month 3 and year 2013 so it isn't produced by cartesian product.